# Returning an iterator or opaque collection in Ruby

Tags: ruby, collections, iterator

I'm often in a situation where I have a class that contains a collection.  I'd like external code to be able to iterate over this collection, but not modify it.

I end up writing something like this:

```
def iter
  @internal_collection.each do |o|
     yield o
  end
end
```

This allows the external code to do:

```
object.iter do |o|
    do_something(o)
end
```

There must be a more elegant way of writing the "iter" method.  Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to say, I tried:

    def iter
        return @collection.each
    end

but I believe that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Before elegance, I would make sure I return an `Enumerator` if no block is given.

This way your users can do `object.iter.with_index do |obj, i|`

An easy way to do this is and shorten your code is:

```
def iter(&block)
  @internal_collection.each(&block)
end
```

In other circumstances, you might want to simply return a copy...

```
def collection
  @internal_collection.dup
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as explicitly writing the method goes, that's about as simple as it gets. But I think what you're after is the Forwardable module. Your code would look like this:

```
require 'forwardable'

class YourClass
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegator :@internal_collection, :each, :iter
end
```

Or if you wanted, you could delegate the whole Enumerable protocol to your internal collection and get all the standard Enumerable behavior that your internal collection features:

```
class YourClass
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@internal_collection, *Enumerable.instance_methods
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nice just to know about in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `dup` and `freeze` on your internal collection, then expose it to the world:

```
def collection
  @internal_collection.dup.freeze
end

collection.map!(&:to_s) #=> raise RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Array
```

Comment: Seems like that must create a heavy-weight copy of the collection -- and thus be inefficient if the method is called frequently.